# dblink returns SQL Error [42703]: ERROR: column "xy" does not exist

Tags: postgresql, dblink

Can someone tell me why i get this error and how i can solve it?

I have a function like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION custom.dblink_function_v21()
 RETURNS TABLE(name character varying, service character varying, scopes character varying)
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
DECLARE
    var_req TEXT;

    rec_key record;
    cur_key CURSOR FOR Select * from dblink(
'host=server1
user=user1
password=pw1
dbname=db1
port=5433',
'
select s.id,s.name,s.host from servers s where s.id IN (465,325) order by s.name
') as (srv character varying,name character varying, host character varying);

BEGIN
open cur_key;
loop
   fetch cur_key into rec_key;
   EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;
  var_req := 'Select * from dblink(
''host=' || rec_key.host || '
user=user2
password=pw2
dbname=db2'',
''
select
' || rec_key.name || ' as name ,
es.name as service,
es.scopes::varchar as scopes
from services es
'') as (srv varchar,service varchar,scopes varchar);
';
return query execute var_req; 

 end loop;
close cur_key;
END
$function$
;
```

when i call it with `select * from custom.dblink_function_v21()` i get this error :

```
SQL Error [42703]: ERROR: column "dba01" does not exist
  Where: Error occurred on dblink connection named "unnamed": could not execute query.
PL/pgSQL function custom.dblink_function_v21() line 43 at RETURN QUERY
```

dba01 is not a column.. it's my first value in column name.

If i just change the `' || rec_key.name || '` too `' || rec_key.srv || '` i suddenly works. But i don't want the id of the server in return i want the name. They both have same datatype and everything so i don't whats the Problem.

Ive been trying different things like crazy but nothing works..

Working with postgres v.10

Comment: You should compose your query strings with `format` so that you are not vulnerable to SQL injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the select statement you create:

```
select XXX as name , es.name as service, es.scopes::varchar as scopes from services es
```

where XXX is the value of rec_key.name - and the value of rec_key.srv in the latter case.

In the former case, the statement evaluates to:

```
select dba01 as name , es.name as service, es.scopes::varchar as scopes from services es
```

but in the latter case:

```
select 100 as name , es.name as service, es.scopes::varchar as scopes from services es
```

In the former case, the error is issued as the column dba01 does not exist.  In the latter case, the number 100 is selected as name.  It is a perfectly valid statement as it is not interpreted as a column name.

If you want to select the text value "dba01" as column "name" you can change that part to:

```
''' || rec_key.name || '''::text as name ,
```

Best regards, Bjarni

Comment: @bjari ragnarsson Thanks for your reply! My column name should be name and dba01 is the first value inside that column. I tried to change as you said ''' || rec_key.name || '''::text as name , but still get the same error :(

Comment: if i run it with ' || rec_key.srv || ' i get the column name srv and values  465 and 326

Comment: You should display var_req (with raise notice '%',var_req; for example) to see what the statement actually looks like.

Comment: Thanks! ''''' || rec_key.name || ''''' was the solution